# Dijkstra's and Prim's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

as I see Dijkstra's and Prim's algorithms are amost the same. Here is the pseudocode from wikipedia, I'll explain the poinf of my confusion.

```
1  function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
2      dist[source] ← 0                                    // Initialization
3
4      create vertex set Q
5
6      for each vertex v in Graph:           
7          if v ≠ source
8              dist[v] ← INFINITY                          // Unknown distance from source to v
9              prev[v] ← UNDEFINED                         // Predecessor of v
10
11         Q.add_with_priority(v, dist[v])
12
13
14     while Q is not empty:                              // The main loop
15         u ← Q.extract_min()                            // Remove and return best vertex
16         for each neighbor v of u:                      // only v that is still in Q
17             alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v) 
18             if alt < dist[v]
19                 dist[v] ← alt
20                 prev[v] ← u
21                 Q.decrease_priority(v, alt)
22
23     return dist[], prev[]
```

Prim's algorithm is almost the same, for convenience, I'll just change the loop that starts in 14th line

```
14     while Q is not empty:                              
15         u ← Q.extract_min()                            
16         for each neighbor v of u:                      
17             if v ∈ Q and length(u, v) < cost[v]
18                 cost[v] ← length(u, v)
19                 prev[v] ← u
20                 Q.decrease_priority(v, length(u, v))
```

There are two changes, the first is replacing `dist[]` with `cost[]` and as I understand this is related to the fact that algorithms solve different problems.
The second one is obscure for me, namely the absence of  `if v ∈ Q` this condition in Dijkstra's algorithm. I don't really get why we CAN return to the set of visited vertices in Prim's algorithm and this CANNOT happen in Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: `if x ∈ Q` What is `x`?

Comment: Missprint, replaced `x` for `v`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dijkstra, we compute `alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)` and set `dist[v]` to `alt` if `alt` is smaller than the current value of `dist[v]`. `alt` represents the distance from the start node to `v` if we go via `u`. However, `u` is the node that was just taken out of `Q`, and so, its distance from the start node is greater than or equal to all other nodes that have previously been taken out of `Q`. Because Dijkstra requires all edge weights to be nonnegative, `alt` is guaranteed to be greater than or equal to `dist[v]` if `v` is not in `Q` since it is the sum of `dist[u]` and `length(u, v)`, and so it won't pass the condition in the `if`. In other words, if `v` is not in `Q`, `u` will be a detour relative to the path we already have to `v`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got your idea right. For both Dijkstra and prims algorithms, we should only deal with the vertex in the Q. 
For the Dijkstra algorithm, the pseudo code may not explicitly check if current vertice is still in Q, but it commented as "only v that is still in Q"

```
 for each neighbor v of u:                      // only v that is still in Q
```

I assume they means the same thing as x ∈ Q

```
17             if x ∈ Q and length(u, v) < cost[v]
```

if the x here represents "v" in line 16.

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra and Prim algorithms are very similar.

The difference is:

- **Prim's algorithm:** Closest vertex to a minimum spanning tree via an undirected edge
- **Dijsktra's algorithm:** Closest vertex to a source via a directed path

*Source: Algorithms by Sedgewick & Wayne*